# Yarn gives me error after "yarn run test " command

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testng, yarnpkg, package.json

I'm new to learn react testing and using different sources for that. One I found is videos of Maximillian 'burger-builder' tutorial and I used it. But after the command run test I get this error and couldn't solve that

```
    {
      "name": "burger-builder",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "babel-core": "6.26.0",
        "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
        "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
        "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
        "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
        "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
        "chalk": "1.1.3",
        "css-loader": "0.28.7",
        "dotenv": "4.0.0",
        "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.3",
        "eslint": "^7.7.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
        "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "1.1.5",
        "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
        "jest": "20.0.4",
        "jest-cli": "^26.4.2",
        "object-assign": "4.1.1",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
        "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
        "promise": "8.0.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "raf": "3.4.0",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
        "resolve": "1.6.0",
        "style-loader": "0.19.0",
        "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
        "url-loader": "0.6.2",
        "webpack": "3.8.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.3",
        "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
        "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node scripts/start.js",
        "build": "node scripts/build.js",
        "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
      },
      "jest": {
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
          "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
          "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
        ],
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
          "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
        ],
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "testURL": "http://localhost",
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
          "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
          "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "web.js",
          "js",
          "json",
          "we b.jsx",
          "jsx",
          "node",
          "mjs"
        ]
      },
      "babel": {
        "presets": [
          "react-app"
        ]
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      }
    }
```

after running yarn run test it giving the following error

[image]

Why I get this error and how can I correct it?

Comment: Do you want to start server? or Do you really want to run test scripts?

Comment: Did you first run ‘npm install’?  If you did, I’d delete “node_modules” then run ‘npm install’ then ‘npm run test’ again

Comment: I deleted node_modules and run again but got the same problem

Comment: I want to run test scripts